# Magento 2: Download order history from Customer account

Tags: magento-2.1.7, download, order-history

From customer account i have to give option to download order history. It will be like table of all order records.
Order #     Date    Ship To     Order Total     Status

Can i have any suggestion or reference please?

Comment: you need to create custom extenison which provide this functionality.

Comment: @Magecode Look at the template file Magento_Sales/templates/order/history.phtml, and the block class which the history.phtml referring to.

Comment: @Magecode have you found something? I am interested for Magento v.2.3.x